# Non trivial lower bound for $\sup_P \|Px\|$ where $x$ is fixed, and the supremum if over all full-rank projection matrices $P \in R^{k \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, singular-values, grassmannian

Let $1 \le k \le n$ be integers and let $G_{n,k}$ be the grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$. For any $U \in G_{n,k}$, let $P_U$ be the orthogonal projection onto from $\mathbb R^n$ to $U$. Fix a unit vector $x \in \mathbb R^d$; for example, WLOG, take $x=(1,0,\ldots,0)$.

> **Question.** What is a good lower-bound for $\alpha_{n,k} := \sup_{U \in G_{n,k}}\|P_U x\|$ ?

### Notes

- Alternatively, one can rewrite $\alpha_{n,k} = \sup_P \|Px\|$, where the supremum if over all rank $k$ projection matrices.
- I know that the answer has to be (much ?) larger than $c\sqrt{k/n}$, since this is the naive lower-bound one gets by considering random $U$ and taking expectations (w.r.t Haar measure on $G_{n,k}$) instead of supremum.

Comment: For a fixed $x \in \Bbb R^n$, presumably we could choose a subspace $U$ that contains $x$, which would mean that $\|P_Ux\| = 1$

Comment: Since every $U \in G_{n,k}$ contains $0$, consider the triangle formed by $0, x, P_Ux$. $\|P_Ux\|$ is one side of this triangle. Since $x$ is fixed, how large can $\|P_Ux\|$ be?